# Windows store apps: ScrollViewer with dynamic content

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have a scrollViewer with an ItemsControl (which holds rows with data) as content. The data from these rows is grabbed from the server so I want to display a ProgressRing with a text until the data arrives. Basically I want the content of the ScrollViewer to be a grid with progress ring and a text and after the data arrives the content to be changed with my ItemsControl.

The problem is that the ScrollViewer does not accept more than 1 element as content. Please tell me how can I solve this problem. (I'm a C# beginner)

```
<FlipView x:Name="OptionPagesFlipView"  Grid.Row="1" TabNavigation="Cycle" SelectionChanged="OptionPagesFlipView_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding OptionsPageItems}">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="OptionMonthPageTemplate">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="OptionsScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="OptionItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding OptionItems, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:Name="OptionsChainItemTemplate">
                                    <Grid x:Name="OptionItemGrid" Background="#FF9DBDF7" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <!-- CALL BID -->
                                        <TextBlock Text="Bid" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="18" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="CallBidTextBlock" Text="{Binding CallBid}" Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,5,5" FontSize="18"/>
                                        <!-- CALL ASK -->
                                        <TextBlock Text="Ask" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="18" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="CallAskTextBlock" Text="{Binding CallAsk}" Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontSize="18"/>
                                        <!-- CALL LAST -->
                                        <TextBlock Text="Last" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="18" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="CallLastTextBlock" Text="{Binding CallLast}" Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,5,5" FontSize="18"/>
                                        <!-- CALL NET CHANGE -->
                                        <TextBlock Text="Net Ch" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="18" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="CallNetChTextBlock" Text="{Binding CallNetChange}" Foreground="{Binding CallNetChangeForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,5,5" FontSize="18"/>
                                        <!-- STRIKE -->
                                        <TextBlock Text="Strike" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="18" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                                        <Border Background="{Binding StrikeBackground}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0,5,5">
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="StrikeTextBlock" Text="{Binding Strike}" Foreground="Blue"  FontSize="18"/>
                                        </Border>
                                        <!-- PUT LAST -->
                                        <TextBlock Text="Last" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="18" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="PutLastTextBlock" Text="{Binding PutLast}" Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5,0,5,5" FontSize="18"/>
                                        <!-- PUT NET CHANGE -->
                                        <TextBlock Text="Net Ch" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="18" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="PutNetChangeTextBlock" Text="{Binding PutNetChange}" Foreground="{Binding PutNetChangeForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5,0,5,5" FontSize="18"/>
                                        <!-- PUT BID -->
                                        <TextBlock Text="Bid" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" FontSize="18" Margin="5,0,15,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="PutBidTextBlock" Text="{Binding PutBid}" Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Margin="5,0,15,5" FontSize="18"/>
                                        <!-- PUT ASK -->
                                        <TextBlock Text="Ask" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" FontSize="18" Margin="5,0,15,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="PutAskTextBlock" Text="{Binding PutAsk}" Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" Margin="5,0,15,5" FontSize="18"/>

                                        <!-- BOTTOM LINE SEPARATOR-->
                                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="3"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                        <!--<Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ProgressRing x:Name="CustomProgressRing" Height="40" Width="40" IsActive="true" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20" Foreground="White"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="CustomTextBlock" Height="auto" Width="auto" FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20"/>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                        </Grid>-->
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a Grid in your scrollviewer, and your two other controls (the ItemsControl and the Grid) in that Grid, like this:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="OptionsScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="OptionItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding OptionItems, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <!-- -->
        </ItemsControl>
        <Grid>
            <!-- -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Note: You'll need to control the Visibility of the Grid with the ProgressRing. You probably want to give it a name so you can do that from C# (I'm assuming yo're controlling the Visibility of the ItemsControl from C# as well).

Comment: Thanks, I will implement it (stupid me I didn't thought about this) and will mark your answer as accepted if works OK.